# IntegrityError at /admin/main/post/add/ NOT NULL constraint failed: main_post.status

Tags: python, django, web

How fix this? This after when i create new post and when i press button 'add'

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. Why stackoverflow ask this?

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField()
    
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to use management commands, `makemigrations` and `migrate` after removing `status` field from your `Post` model. As far as I can see you don't have status field in your model but this field is still exists in your database. So make sure that field is properly removed from your database by using these management commands (`makemigrations` and `migrate`) or if your data is not important you can do the following procedure:

a- Drop your database and create new one

b- Remove all migration files

c- Run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`